# How to replace or update item of array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

The title describes what I want, this is the code

All is fine when we add a product to `items` if it doesn't exists (difference by id). But if it exists, I want to modify only the item. The difference is made by id of each item in `items` array.

Eg : if first, id = 1, qty = 3, and next, id = 1, qty = 3, I want the update of qty in `items`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#fact',
  data: {
    input: {
      id: null,
      qty: 1
    },
    items: []
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      var item = {
        id: this.input.id,
        qty: this.input.qty
      };
      
      if(index = this.itemExists(item) !== false)
      {
          this.items.slice(index, 1, item);
          return null;
      }
      
      this.items.push(item)
    },
    itemExists($input){
       for (var i = 0, c = this.items.length; i < c; i++) {
           if (this.items[i].id == $input.id) {
               return i;
          }
       }
       return false;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<Doctype html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Add product</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="fact">
      <p>
        <input type="text" v-model="input.id" placeholder="id of product" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="text" v-model="input.qty" placeholder="quantity of product" />
      </p>
      <button @click="addItem">Add</button>

      <ul v-if="items.length > 0">
        <li v-for="item in items">{{ item.qty + ' ' + item.id }}</li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have misused the `slice` method, [change `slice` to `splice`](https://jsfiddle.net/r47u70ec/) works for me:

```
this.items.splice(index, 1, item)
```

`slice` doesn't trigger view updates according to the [documentation here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods).

> Vue wraps an observed array’s mutation methods so they will also
> trigger view updates. The wrapped methods are:
>
> - push()
> - pop()
> - shift()
> - unshift()
> - splice()
> - sort()
> - reverse()

Comment: Thank you for this remark! But even modifying, he adds this time the item in question. By cons I want the `item` already added in `items` is changed!

Comment: By using `splice(index, 1, item)`, you replace the original item with the new item. If you have other fields, you might use Object.assign to create a new item that merge into the original item and then replace it. Something like: `splice(index, 1, Object.assign({}, this.items[index], item))`.

Comment: Directly modifying the item in place won't be a good idea because Vue can't detect the changes you made.  See [Caveates](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats).

Comment: Thank you for your assistance ! after a moment to check what it wasn't work, I discover `if(index = this.itemExists(item) !== false)` that would be `(index = this.itemExists(item)) !== false)`. With the same code, of course your remark  included (`splice` instand of `slice`), all is work fine now ! Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

```
if(index = this.itemExists(item) !== false)
{
    for (let value of this.items) {
        if(value.id === item.id) {
            value.qty = item.qty;
        }
     }

     return null;
 }
```

Comment: The difference is made by id of item (`item.id`) , do you think realy that it will help me ?

Comment: _While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion_